# How can I align vertices to an axis?

Tags: mirror

I'm not sure how to ask this question. Basically, I built a part in the right half of my screen, looking at it from the Y perspective (numpad 1). I applied a mirror modifier, across the X axis. I left a gap in the middle so that I could more easily create the part. Now I want to scoot the part along the X axis so that there is no gap in the middle. I know how to move the whole part together, but how can I move it so that the leftmost vertices are exactly stuck together, completely eliminating the gap?

[image: Part with gap in it.]

Comment: Check out "Clipping" in the mirror moddifier. Then see what happens when you move the parts together.

Comment: That's pretty close to what I want, but how can I snap the grab to the mirrored vertex so that I can be absolutely sure that the parts have zero space between them and retain their original size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's annoying that, in Edit Mode, Blender's *Snap To : Increment* doesn't have a *Snap With* option, otherwise this would be more intuitive.

In this case, if you have the shipped add-on  '3D View: Pie Menus' activated with the 'Origins' option, you can quickly set the origin of your object to the vertices of the desired mirror-plane from Edit Mode, and the mirrored half will jump to the original. Then you can <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> reset the object back to World 0.

But personally, rather than puzzle over each case, for more CAD-like snapping, my habit is to create temporary snap targets.

[image]

With snapping nearly always set to *To : Vertex* and *With : Active*, and the pivot set to 3D Cursor:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> duplicate a single vertex..
2. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> scale the vertex to 0
3. Select the source vertex, (it will stay active), and <kbd>L</kbd> all the connected ones
4. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> Move the selected vertices, snapping to the temporary target
5. Delete, or merge, the target.

I wouldn't claim this is necessarily the quickest for this case, but the method is quite *general*. You can leave your pivot and snap settings as they are over most operations, and the sequence goes into muscle-memory.

Comment: Thank you, this is more or less exactly what I needed. I don't mind if it's a little slow, as long as it's generally applicable. My only question: how did you use scale to set the vertex's X to 0? When I did that, nothing happened. I just edited the position of the vertex manually.

Comment: Hi @alskdjfoijowiejf ! (thank God I don't have to type that :) )    With the pivot set to '3D Cursor', and the cursor at 0, SX0 should do the trick. Actually, you could: Shift-D,S-X-0, all in one. but my muscles don't remember that much :D.

Answer (score 3):

In edit mode select a vertex to the left of your model press <kbd>N</kbd> to see the "Item"->"Transform" panel. Select "Global" and copy values from X field.

[image: edit mode]

<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of edit mode and in same panel subtract the copied X value from current object location.

[image: object mode]

This moves the object to the left by exactly the amount needed to put the vertex you selected at the very beginning on the X = 0.

[image: x is zero]

Sometime it doesn't work perfectly, and slight adjustment at the very end is necessary.